# What do the Brackets in MATLAB's ga function do?

Tags: matlab

On [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/constrained-minimization-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html#zmw57dd0e1947), MATLAB's genetic algorithm was used as:

```
ObjectiveFunction = @simple_fitness;
nvars = 2;    % Number of variables
LB = [0 0];   % Lower bound
UB = [1 13];  % Upper bound
ConstraintFunction = @simple_constraint;
[x,fval] = ga(ObjectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB, ...
    ConstraintFunction)
```

What do the brackets do in this function, and why are there four of them? I noticed if I remove a `[]`, I get the error `GA requires the following inputs to be of data type double: 'ub'`.

I have been trying to use `ga` to solve another optimization problem with different constraints, but I could not properly input them into the function and could not find information on what those brackets do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` simply means that you do not specify those inputs, squared brackets are required because you define other inputs after the non-specified ones. The reason for that is that for many functions the input arguments are identified by their 'number', order. So if you remove a `[]` from the above example Matlab will think that you defined a different input argument than you intended/original.

Comment: Just to nitpick, `[]` means empty array as the input and that is what is specified.  It is up to the function to handle an empty matrix for any given input.  In general you can't give `[]` for an arbitrary input and expect the function to use a default, although that is often the case.